# Converting simple code to a math expression

Tags: summation

I am curious if there is a way of somehow recreating such code as a math statement.

```
S = [1,2,3,4]
output = 0

for x in S:
    
    N = S.copy()
    N[x-1] = 0
    
    for y in N:
        output = output + y
```

The only thing that I could think of is reminiscent of something like this, but I have no clue how I could change the numbers in the second array, nor how to duplicate the array. $$\sum_{x \in S}{\sum_{y \in N}{y}}$$

The solution is 30. ( 0+2+3+4+1+0+3+4+1+2+0+4+1+2+3+0)

Comment: So if I understand correctly this is $(|S|-1)\sum_{x\in S} x$.

Comment: Connecting correct record for input sum and comment of Snaw, one can write $\sum_{x\in S}\sum_{y\in S,y\neq x} y = (|S|-1) \sum_{x\in S} x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite your code a bit:

```
S = [1,2,3,4]
output = 0

for x in S:
    output += sum(S) - S[x - 1]
```

Or equivalently, `output = len(S) * sum(S) - sum(S[x - 1] for x in S)`. Therefore, we can write it as (0-indexed)

$$|S|\sum S - \sum_{x\in S} S[x - 1]$$

Though as you can tell, it depends very specifically on what $S$ is, and that order matters.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be written as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{x=1}^4\sum_{{y=1}\atop{y\ne x}}^4 y}\tag{1}
&=\sum_{x=1}^4\left(\sum_{y=1}^4y-x\right)\\
&=4\sum_{y=1}^4y-\sum_{x=1}^4x\\
&=3\sum_{x=1}^4 x\\
&=3\,\frac{4\cdot 5}{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=30}
\end{align*}
resulting in $30$ as stated by OP. Here the left-hand sum of (1) represents rather verbatim the two for-loops written as double sum.